# Do we have or need a New-Pet Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

There is a recent question [What things I should prepare before having a dog](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13448/what-things-i-should-prepare-before-having-a-dog).  I feel like we should probably already have that question, but I am not finding it.

Maybe we need a tag like 'New-Pet' or 'First-Pet' or something for more general questions?

Answer (score 3):

It's pretty similar to the tag concept of "beginner" and I'm not sure if that tag has a lot of value in narrowing things down for people. While some pets have similar start up needs, they're not really that interchangeable by and large. For example, the needs for first time dog are quite different than the needs for first time iguana, so what does that tag really help define for the questions?

Comment: It would help when combing tags.there are more then 1,000 questions with the dog tag, there are [currently 59 tagged for dogs and diet](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dogs+diet) combining the tag beginner/new/first with dog or iguana would get you to all the new pet owner questions for the species.

Comment: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

Answer (score -2):

I think new-pet is a better fit rather than first-pet, since a first pet is by definition a new pet, while a new pet won't always be your first pet.

As for John's comment regarding the narrowing of questions, that's when the dog, cat, reptile, and etc tags come into place, giving the question more identity by using a combination of two tags which in my opinion will be beneficial to the site.

The only real issue here, would be the use of the tag, how many questions do we have regarding new pets?